# Pyspark : Join 2 dataframe to get only new records from 2nd dataframe (Historisation)

Tags: join, apache-spark-sql, pyspark

I have 2 dataframe df1 and df2. I want result of this dataframe like this :
1. Take all records of df1.
2. Take only new records from df2 (records which are not available in df1)
3. Generate new dataframe of this logic

**Note :** Primary key is "id". I want to check on only id and not complete row. If Id is not available in df1 then only tale from df2.

**df1**

```
    +------+-------------+-----+
    |  id  |time         |other|
    +------+-------------+-----+
    |   111|  29-12-2019 |   p1|
    |   222|  29-12-2019 |   p2|
    |   333|  29-12-2019 |   p3|
    +----+-----+-----+---------+
```

**df2**

```
    +------+-------------+-----+
    |  id  |time         |other|
    +------+-------------+-----+
    |   111|  30-12-2019 |   p7|
    |   222|  30-12-2019 |   p8|
    |   444|  30-12-2019 |   p0|
    +----+-----+-----+---------+
```

**Result**

```
+------+-------------+-----+
|  id  |time         |other|
+------+-------------+-----+
|   111|  29-12-2019 |   p1|
|   222|  29-12-2019 |   p2|
|   333|  29-12-2019 |   p3|
|   444|  30-12-2019 |   p0|
+----+-----+-----+---------+
```

Could you please help me how to do this in pyspark. I am planning to use join.

Answer (score 0):

```
df1=spark.createDataFrame([(111,'29-12-2019','p1'),(222,'29-12-2019','p2'),(333,'29-12-2019','p3')],['id','time','other'])
df2=spark.createDataFrame([(111,'30-12-2019','p7'),(222,'30-12-2019','p8'),(444,'30-12-2019','p0')],['id','time','other'])

mvv1 = df1.select("id").rdd.flatMap(lambda x: x).collect()
print(mvv1)

[111, 222, 333]

yy=",".join([str(x) for x in mvv1])
df2.registerTempTable("temp_df2")
sqlDF2 = sqlContext.sql("select * from temp_df2 where id not in ("+yy+")")
sqlDF2.show()

+---+----------+-----+
| id|      time|other|
+---+----------+-----+
|444|30-12-2019|   p0|
+---+----------+-----+

df1.union(sqlDF2).show()

+---+----------+-----+
| id|      time|other|
+---+----------+-----+
|111|29-12-2019|   p1|
|222|29-12-2019|   p2|
|333|29-12-2019|   p3|
|444|30-12-2019|   p0|
+---+----------+-----+
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I have millions of records and doing union is cause memory issue. Its slower to use union to this much records. how about join and using subtract or except?

Comment: Join is one of the most expensive operations you will commonly use in Spark, so it is worth doing what you can to shrink your data before performing a join.

Comment: I guess yes for merging 2 table with this many records join could be very expensive so I have used join just to filter new records and using UNION for final output.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I wrote this code and seems working fine for 12,000,000 rows its only taking 5 minute to build. I hope it helps others :

```
df1=spark.createDataFrame([(111,'29-12-2019','p1'),(222,'29-12-2019','p2'),(333,'29-12-2019','p3')],['id','time','other'])
df2=spark.createDataFrame([(111,'30-12-2019','p7'),(222,'30-12-2019','p8'),(444,'30-12-2019','p0')],['id','time','other'])

#So this is giving me all records which are not available in df1 dataset
new_input_df = df2.join(df1, on=['id'], how='left_anti')

#Now union df1(historic reocrds) and new_input_df  which contains only new 
final_df = df1.union(new_input_df)

final_df.show()
```